# close button on the left or right side?

Tags: position, close, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the important aspect to consider when deciding where windows interaction buttons should be placed?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7/what-is-the-important-aspect-to-consider-when-deciding-where-windows-interaction)

From a ux point of view, does it make a difference if the close button is on the right of a window's title bar, like on microsoft windows, or on the left side, like on mac OS?

Comment: My gut would say ALWAYS IN THE UPPER RIGHT but your question just made me realize that I instantly go up to the upper left on my Mac and upper right on my PC. So it does seem like a very OS-centric habit.

Comment: Windows (Certainly on Xp) has a 2nd hidden close button on the top left of any window:  double click the icon on the far left on the blue bar and it closes the window. I use both the left and right close buttons.

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/ok-cancel-on-left-right

Comment: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/submit-buttons-on-the-left-or-the-right

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would definitely go with top right, because more people use windows than mac, and those who use mac, just like you, know that generally close button is in the top right corner.

Remember where are you looking for the close button when you get a layer pop-up in a browser window?

Answer (score 6):

That would depend on whether you are using Windows or OSX and perhaps whether you are left or right handed and whether you are using a mouse or a touch screen.

Nevertheless - a left handed touch screen user on windows will probably out of familiarity with a majority of software *expect* to find the button on the right.

Generally - don't depart from the fundamental norm. If users expect to find something somewhere (because everyone else on the planet does) then you've got to have a ***really*** good reason not to do the same!

Other than that - the typical workflow for a (non Hebrew speaking?) user is from left to right - it would seem more logical therefore when trying to get final closure on a window that it be at the right along with other finalization buttons, notwithstanding the working conditions in my first paragraph.

There are inevitably going to be some for whom the left is preferred and some for whom the right is preferred, so you can only cater for best experience for the majority, not for all.

Answer (score 2):

From my childhood age onwards I worked in Windows only. In windows usually I use to close the window by double clicking the left windows title bar and more of friends use that technique only. Because we always use to read the text from left to right so it is easy for us to close the window quickly if it is in left side. For the Past 5 months only I working on mac now it become more easy for me to close the window just a single click.

Answer (score 1):

Even as a fortunate Mac-only user (since 7 years) I would still instinctively look **top right** in any context other than my Mac desktop. Facebook has them top right. That's kind of standard nowadays, right?

Comment: And yet you can still double-click the top left of Windows windows to close them.